# Yosemite driver, can't load Force Feedback driver

Tags: driver, osx-yosemite, iokit, kernel-extension

I am working on updating the Mac OS X driver for the Xbox 360 controller. With the introduction of Yosemite, non-Apple kernel extensions need to be stored in `/Library/Extensions` as opposed to `/System/Library/Extensions` and must be signed. The IOKit driver has a plug-in inside of it that has the force feedback driver. However, when the driver is in any other position other than `/System/Library/Extensions`, it doesn't load the force feedback plug-in.

I think I'll need to edit the `IOCFPlugInTypes`, which currently points to `360Controller.kext/Contents/PlugIns/Feedback360.plugin`, to something else. I can't find anything about it on Apple's developer pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the Apple-approved method to work around this issue is to add a symbolic link in `/System/Library/Extensions` that references your own kext in `/Library/Extensions`. Kext look-up will ignore the symbolic link, but (in this example) Force Feedback will go through the symlink to get the plug-in.